# How do I connect to SSAS via SSMS? (cryptic errors galore)

Tags: connection, database-connection, ssas

I'm trying to connect to an SSAS server via SSMS (the preferred client I'd guess but who knows).
I'm entering
Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User Id = xxxxx;password=xxxxx;Provider=MSOLAP.7 (this one is optional I think); Format=Tabular (this one also optional);

The SSMS was version 17.x but I downloaded 17.9 (most recent) as well.
The SSAS version? Well, who knows, I can't connect. The 'creator' is long gone. Actually via Visual Studio it looks like 10.0.5500.0.

ALL CREDENTIALS ARE ACCURATE.
I get the following error

```
"Element 'return' was not found. Line 5, position 2. (System.Xml)"
```

The credentials are reading as accurate because changing the user ID or password to anything else results in a different "connection denied" error. So the credentials are being accepted.
ALSO I can connect to the SSAS server just fine using Visual Studio 2015. It connects and shows me all tables.

So WHY the cryptic error in SSMS? What file or .jar or .dll or whatchamacallit BS is necessary here?
Googling the cryptic error message reveals nothing, so I wouldn't try. It only shows one Microsoft Peon claiming it's a connection timeout setting thing and to raise that. It's not that, and raising it does nothing.

So anyone know what to do here?
I'm not even concerned with deducing what the error means per se; is there a checklist in how to connect to SSAS with SSMS? All the credentials are right. I'm using the same connection string in MS Visual Studio 2015.

In Visual Studio 2015, I am selecting ".Net Framework Data Provider for OLE DB" and then "MS OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services Version X.0"
In SSMS, I'm selecting Analysis Services connection, and using the Windows Authentication (with connection string that provides user id and password, again the credentials are being accepted, there is a random cryptic error).

What's going on here? Very frustrating.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the SSMS connection dialog before you click connect?

Comment: Wouldn't that have server/ password info in it?

Comment: Feel free to type in fake server names and usernames. But a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: I think I figured it out. In part. The user/ ID is something other than my personal windows login (e.g. instead of JoeSmith it was yeOldeServiceAccount). The Dev showed me to remote into the server first (as the ServiceAccount) -- and then when I logged into SSAS using Windows Auth, it worked fine. On my personal computer (non-remote) I'm still JoeSmith. Even if I pass along the user-id/ password in the connection string, it fails. NOW, it does somehow "know" those credentials are correct (different error message otherwise) -- but since I'm not "impersonating" that user in Windows correctly

Comment: Then it fails. Still --- why does Windows require Win Authen logins for SSAS? Why can't they enable an optional User ID / Password like SQL Server in general? And why doesn't it say access denied but "line item missing" BS? It somehow verifies the credentials as correct, but rejects the method. Eh. Anyway. This probably would be greatly simplified if they just gave my personal account the rights instead of some hippy dippy service account that some retired accountant used for a while. Whatever. I stopped asking questions for some of this stuff here a while ago